# Unsupported SD format renders my micro SD card useless. Is there a way to fix it?

Tags: rom-flashing, sd-card, formatting

I have just flashed a new ROM and the microSD card is gone. It appears in the notifications as "unsupported SD card". Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug it into PC and format it to FAT32. That should done the trick. Or maybe you can format it trought phone take a look for that option in storage settings.

Comment: It is not recognized at all (PC, mobile...neither can see it). I have formatted it by the ROM but it is still not recognizable.

Comment: Done. I have just reformatted it into FAT32 using an SD card adapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the suggestions I could find on the web, including third-party-software, but none of them worked! My SD card was neither accessible on the device itself (via file explorers) nor on a PC. (I didn't expect to be able to access it on the PC, though, as I had "adopted" it as internal storage on my (non-rooted) Android device, so it was encrypted.)

Surprisingly, I was able to access the SD card with [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/):

- `adb shell ls \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`: List all folders on sdcard
- `adb shell du -hs \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/*`: Check size of folders on sdcard
- `adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`: Print out SD card folder name; in my case: `/sdcard`
- `adb pull <SD card folder>`, e.g. `adb pull sdcard`: Download all files and folders from sdcard to current directory. Depending on the folder size and number of files, this may take very long. It may be better to download only the folders required: `adb pull <SD card folder>/<path to be downloaded>`.

I was even more surprised to find out that some of the files on the SD card were updated that very day, e.g. the WhatsApp backup, even though I had not been able to access the SD card for months and was always getting the "unsupported SD card" on start-up. I seems that a number of apps were still able to access it.

---

*EDIT:*

I just saw that `sdcard` is a symbolic link to my primary storage: `/storage/self/primary`! So it may not have been my original sdcard content I was viewing and copying but data added since my SD card got corrupted (and Android added the symbolic link to allow apps to use the internal storage as if it was an sdcard). The alternative is that adopting an sdcard as internal storage leads to this symbolic link. I find the former more likely, but cannot evaluate that in my case, as my SD card had been corrupted for a long time now.